# X-axis alignment for Columnrange

Tags: highcharts

I can't get the x axis to be aligned with the values I specified
(There is a reason why I have specified each "point" as it's own serie)
Please see this JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3gh0tqdw/

```
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [
        {
            id: 'series1',
            name: 'series1',
            data:[[0, 0, 20]]
        },
        {
            id: 'series2',
            name: 'series2',
            data:[[1, 5, 20]]
        },
        {
            id: 'series3',
            name: 'series3',
            data:[[2, 0, 20]]
        },
        {
            name: 'series5',
            id: 'series4',
            data:[[3, 5, 20]]
        }
    ]
});
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set [grouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.columnrange.grouping) parameter as false.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3gh0tqdw/1/

```
plotOptions:{
        series:{
            grouping:false
        }
},
```